# Blank frame for jQuery Mobile Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am integrating Google Maps with jQuery Mobile and .NET. I am following the Google Code (example 4) documentation here: http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html#jquery-mobile-example-4.html

I've been careful in transferring the code, but I keep receiving a blank frame. The map doesn't show up in the frame.

Anyone else run into this problem? Any recommendations on additional documentation, tutorials, videos, and reading?

I greatly appreciate anyone's time and help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time and help. After more research and additional help from others, I was able to find a Google Maps solution to get me moving more quickly. A great conversation that outlines resources I studied, used, and highlighted can be found [in this google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-map-discuss/browse_thread/thread/3bea5eb5922d1eae?pli=1).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is outlined here : http://www.smashinglabs.pl/gmap/examples

> If, for any reason, any dimension of div will be equal 0 during
>   loading process, maps will stop working correctly. It is quite common
>   issue while loading tabs, accordions, etc.

He goes on to outline specific problem resolutions. Some of them:

- Try calling the 'refresh' function manually `google.maps.event.trigger($('#map').data('gmap').gmap, 'resize');`
- If your `#map` container doesn't have a set size, it will default to 0x0 by normal HTML/CSS standards. Try setting a size manually, say 300x300
- [etc...](http://www.smashinglabs.pl/gmap/examples)

Answer (score 0):

It might be the google loader api key? (If you copy paste). Get any JS errors?
As Phill said, post some code and we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: After doing some research and getting help from a colleague, it was discovered the the API was providing an error. With a few other tweaks, we got the map working. However, not I'm just stuck on something that seems small. I'm trying to make the default view to SATELLITE. I have the following code, and it runs me back to being blank again:

Comment: '    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#map-canvas').googleMaps({
                latitude: 42.420546, longitude: -83.431003, depth: 16, 
                markers: { latitude: 42.421688, longitude: -83.428964,
                    info: { layer: '#marker' }
                }
    controls: { setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP); }
            });
        }); 
    </script>'

Comment: The map view is under controls, right? What am I missing or mistyping?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery.ui.maps thats the wrong syntax. From what i can tell you are using another plugin.